# Integration $\frac{\sin(x)p(x)}{q(x)}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration

Can we integrate this function: 
$$\int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{x^2 \sin(xr)}{x^2+a^2-ca^2x}\,dx$$ ?

Comment: The  fraction is not convergent to 0 when x→∞.

Comment: @JoJomax the convergence of the integrand is not a neccesary condition for the improper Riemann integral, see for example the integral of $\sin(x^2)$.

Comment: @Botond Yes You are right .Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The fraction goes to $1$ at $+\infty$. If it were Improper Riemann integrable, then we would have that $\forall \varepsilon > 0$, $\exists c>$ so that $\lvert \int_a^b f \rvert < \varepsilon \forall c<a<b$. Let $1>\delta>0$ be given.We can find $c$ big enough to have that
$$g(x):=\frac{x^2}{x^2+a^2-ca^2x}\geqslant 1-\delta$$
Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be given with $2n\pi \geqslant c$. Then, we have that
$$\int_{2n\pi}^{2n \pi +\pi} \sin(x)g(x)\mathrm{d}x \geqslant \int_{2n\pi}^{2n \pi+\pi} \sin(x)(1-\delta) \mathrm{d}x=2(1-\delta)$$
But this contradicts the criterion mentioned at the beggining, so it's not integrable.